# Change color of multiple LI items in javascript when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, css-selectors

I want to change the color of all li using javascript.

Every item/li has its own id with a different color. Now I have added a button and want all items to change color to black when clicking on it.

I have used a function to do this, however, only the first item turns black when clicking on the button (the others don't change their color). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    <html>  
 <body>
   <ul>
      <li id="one">Item1</li>
      <li id="two">Item2</li>
      <li id="three">Item3</li>
      </ul>
   <button onclick="changecolor()">Black</button>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
function changecolor() {
  document.querySelector("#one, #two, #three").style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```

Comment: `querySelector` returns a single element. Use `querySelectorAll` instead and iterate over all matching elements.

Comment: You can try: `function changecolor() {
    var coll = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
    for (var i = 0, len = coll.length; i < len; i++) {
        coll[i].style.color = "blue";
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and give all your list items this same class. On click you would only have to change the class's color.

Comment: Thanks Luis Moita, I've tried that too. Added a class to the UL `<ul class="listbox">` and `function changecolor() {
  document.querySelector(".listbox").style.color = "black";` but that's not working either...